# PHP append to file without new line

Tags: php

I am currently needing some PHP code to append the variable `$domain` to the file `fqdn`. It needs a space between it and the previous domain for scripting reasons.

Here is the PHP that does that:

```
$file = file_get_contents('fqdn');
$file .= ' '.$domain;
file_put_contents('fqdn',$file);
```

However, this creates a new line which makes it impossible to work with script. Please help me.

Regards,

P.S. I did this at 12:30AM so I may have messed up badly.

Comment: what ever it is, i bet a Relational database is a better idea than a flat text file

Comment: maybe the problem is in your file `fqdn` not the `file_put_contents` function

Comment: Even if it's just a SQLite file, still way better than reinventing the wheel

Comment: Maybe the new line is already in the fqdn. If it's a single line, try to remove all new lines on it before using file_put_contents.

Answer (score 0):

It would be more efficient to just open the file for writing since you don't really need its current content. Also make sure you `trim()` the content you insert at the end of the file

```
$handle = fopen("fqdn", "a");
fwrite($handle, trim(' '.$domain));
fclose($handle);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use APPEND flag:

```
<?php
    $sAppendedContents = ' ' . rand();
    file_put_contents( 'fqdn', $sAppendedContents, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX );
?>
```